# In Swift how do I add an additional argument to my function to send the string corresponding to a variable in a .json file

Tags: ios, swift

I'm totally new to programming and have been learning Swift via a number of online courses. In one of these we built a trivia game app and in my spare time I've been playing with the code to improve it (best way to learn I figure!)

The app loads all the questions and answers from a .json file which contains the data in the following format:

```
{
    "id" : "1",
    "question": "Earth is a:",
         "answers": [
        "Planet",
        "Meteor",
        "Star",
        "Asteroid"
      ],
      "difficulty": "1"
  }
```

The correct answer is always the first one listed. Now, the app presents the question and answers with the following function:

```
func loadQuestions(index : Int)
    {
        let entry : NSDictionary = allEntries.objectAtIndex(index) as! NSDictionary
        let question : NSString = entry.objectForKey("question") as! NSString
        let arr : NSMutableArray = entry.objectForKey("answers") as! NSMutableArray

        //println(question)
        //println(arr)

        labelQuestion.text = question as String

        let indices : [Int] = [0,1,2,3]
        //let newSequence = shuffle(indices)
        let newSequence = indices.shuffle()
        var i : Int = 0
        for(i = 0; i < newSequence.count; i++)
        {
            let index = newSequence[i]
            if(index == 0)
            {
                // we need to store the correct answer index
                currentCorrectAnswerIndex =  i

            }

            let answer = arr.objectAtIndex(index) as! NSString
            switch(i)
            {
            case 0:
                buttonA.setTitle(answer as String, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
                break;

            case 1:
                buttonB.setTitle(answer as String, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
                break;

            case 2:
                buttonC.setTitle(answer as String, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
                break;

            case 3:
                buttonD.setTitle(answer as String, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
                break;

            default:
                break;
            }
}
```

What I want to do is add an additional argument that sends the string corresponding to the answer index to a variable named `answertext` so that I can then use this variable as a string in labels (for example, to reveal the correct answer). Now, if I understand the above code correctly, what I'm wanting to do is to basically send an NSString as a String.

I've researched this for a couple of days and I'm pretty sure what I want to do is possible. I've looked at using `switch` and `if else`, but have had no success.

**My question is: How do I do this?**

Any code examples or referrals to further reading would be most appreciated. Alternatively, if you're providing the actual code I'd appreciate a brief explanation of how it works. I'm using the latest Xcode and Swift.

Or, if what I want to do isn't possible, please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like a pretty simple request to me. If you want to store the correct answer in a variable just define the variable at the top of your class like this..

```
var answertext:String?
```

Then inside your `loadQuestions` method store the correct answer **before** you shuffle the array - it's probably best to do this straight after you get the answers array like this.

```
let arr : NSMutableArray = entry.objectForKey("answers") as! NSMutableArray
if let a = arr.objectAtIndex(0) as? String {
    self.answertext = a
}
```

Because we defined the `answertext` variable as an optional using `?` - you will need to un-wrap it later on when you access it like this.

```
if let a = self.answertext {
    self.label.text = "the answer was \(a)"
}
```

Let me know if this is what you were looking for.

Comment: Wow, we're getting close! And your explanations actually made sense (thanks!). The only problem is that it doesn't always display the correct answer for some reason. For example, I played a 10 question game twice and deliberately answered all questions wrong. The app displayed the correct answer on 3 occasions the first time and 4 occasions the second time. I _think_ what is happening is that it is getting the answer correct whenever the correct answer happens to also be listed first, otherwise it's wrong because the app shuffles the answers so that the correct one isn't always listed first.

Comment: Cool, glad it helped.. I have update the answer so that you store the correct answer before you shuffle the array.

Comment: Yes, that worked! I'll do a bit of further reading to get my head around it, so I can truly understand it, but you've broken it down nicely for me! :)